Google Pay Button Missing with Stripe Direct Charges in Test Mode
I'm implementing Stripe Connect and recently switched from destination charges to direct charges. Since then, I can no longer see the Google Pay button in the payment sheet when in test mode.
Previously, with destination charges, the Google Pay button was visible and worked just fine.
When I'm using this check, the result is: Google Pay is supported:
if (!(await isPlatformPaySupported({ googlePay: { testEnv: true } }))) {
  Alert.alert('Google Pay is not supported.');
  return;
} else {
  console.log('google pay supported');
  Alert.alert('Google Pay is supported.');
}

However, the button doesn't show up when I use direct charges. Below is the code I'm using:
return (
  <StripeProvider
    publishableKey={STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY}
    stripeAccountId={organizerAccountId} 
    merchantIdentifier={STRIPE_MERCHANT_IDENTIFIER}>
    <View style={styles.paymentView} />
  </StripeProvider>
);

   const { error } = await initPaymentSheet({
            paymentIntentClientSecret: response.clientSecret,
            merchantDisplayName: 'XXX GmbH',
            googlePay: {
              merchantCountryCode: 'DE',
              testEnv: true,
            },
            applePay: {
              merchantCountryCode: 'DE',
            },
          });

const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create(
  {
    amount: amountToUse,
    currency: currency,
    description: paymentDescription,
    metadata: {
      userEmail: user.email,
      userName: user.name,
      eventName: eventDetails.title,
      eventStartDate: formattedDate,
    },
    payment_method_types: ['card', 'klarna'], 
    receipt_email: user.email
  },
  {
    stripeAccount: organizerStripeAccountId, 
  }
);

If I switch back to destination charges by removing stripeAccountId from the  and adding the transfer_data: { destination } parameter in the payment intent, the Google Pay button appears as expected.
Is there any way to make this work?

I suspect that you have GooglePay set up on your Platform account and it works when you use Destination Charges. However, when using Direct Charges, you may not have set up GooglePay. You need to ensure that the Connected Account has GooglePay enabled and registered the domain on your Connected Accounts: https://docs.stripe.com/payments/payment-methods/pmd-registration?dashboard-or-api=api#register-your-domain-while-using-connect. Can you try this?

I think that's the solution: https://docs.stripe.com/connect/multiple-payment-method-configurations I found out Google Pay was off by default on connected accounts. I changed it to on by default and it's working.
